# grep IPs and port number into one line

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, regular-expression, nmap

Using grep and cut  I have returned the IP and ports of the nmap scan result which looks like this:

```
192.168.1.221
80
443
192.168.1.223
25
```

Desired output:

```
192.168.1.221:80
192.168.1.221:443
192.168.1.223:25
```

Comment: It would be useful to see the shape of your starting point.

Comment: Hey roaima you can find my starting point here [initial post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54988802/filtering-nmap-script-output-format-ipport)

Comment: Posting on multiple sites is off-topc for U&L. If you want to delete your original post then then one becomes on-topic.

Comment: duly noted roaima

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/\./{ip = $0; next}; {print ip":"$0}'
```

should be enough on that input.

Note that `nmap` has options to output in formats suitable for programmatic processing like `xml`.

Comment: Hey @KIllua, please read https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and accept this answer if it best suits you.

Answer (score 0):

One solution with a bash script:

```
for i in $(<input); do [ ${#i} -le 3 ] && printf '%s:%s\n' $ip $i || ip=$i; done
```

This saves the ip address in a variable if the input string length is greater than 3 characters and prints `ip:port` otherwise.
Replace `input` with your input file. (You can choose a greater value to match if your port numbers have more than 3 characters)

Another one:

```
while read i; do [ ${i/.} != $i ] && ip=$i || printf "%s:%s\n" $ip $i; done <input
```

This assigns the ip address to variable `ip` if it contains a dot and prints `ip:port` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something as the following using `awk`:

```
awk '$1 ~ /[0-9]\.[0-9]+/{ip=$1; val=0; next } /^[0-9]+$/{port=$1; if(!(val++)); print ip":"port}' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done by below method

```
sed -n '/^[0-9]\{3\}\./,+1p' filename| sed "N;s/\n/:/g"
```

output

```
192.168.1.221:80
192.168.1.223:25
```

Comment: The output is missing port 443

Comment: Will check and update